# UISearchController search bar does not hide navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, rubymotion

I have a `UITableViewController` as the root of my `UINavigationController`. Activating the search bar does not hide the navigation bar. I have tried so many different configurations and none of them seem to work.

```
class TableViewController < UITableViewController
  def viewDidLoad
    search_controller = UISearchController.alloc.initWithSearchResultsController(nil)
    search_controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
    search_controller.searchBar.delegate = self
    search_controller.searchBar.sizeToFit
    self.definesPresentationContext = true

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = search_controller.searchBar
  end
end
```

Here's what my screen looks like when it's activated.

[image]

Why is this not working as intended?

Edit: the view is not dimming as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The `UISearchController` needs to be assigned to a class variable so that the compiler does not dispose it.

```
@search_controller = UISearchController.alloc
    .initWithSearchResultsController(nil)
@search_controller.searchBar.sizeToFit
@search_controller.searchBar.delegate = self

table_header_view @search_controller.searchBar
```

Hope this helps someone in the future so they don't have to waste hours wondering why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this line, I would think this would solve your issue:

```
search_controller. hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
```